# Why does this quicksort program not give an output?

Tags: c++, quicksort

I am giving an integer array as input to an int array and I am expecting an output of sorted ints.
But  there is no output.

I tried to use a recursive quicksort algo that will take an array of ints as input and give out a sorted array as output. I was expecting the sorted array to be shown in the terminal but there was no output.
This is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 10
using namespace std;
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
  int temp = *a;
  *a  = *b;
  *b = temp;
}
int partition(int* array,int p, int q)
{
   int key = array[p];
   int i = p;
   for(int j = p+1; j <= q; j++ )
   {
    if(key > array[j])
    {
       i++;
       swap(&array[i],&array[j]);
    }
   }
   swap(&array[i],&array[p]);
   return i;
}
void quicksort(int* array,int p,int q)
{
    if(p < q)
    {
     int r = partition(array,p,q);
     quicksort(array,p,r-1);
     quicksort(array,r,q);
    }
}
int main()
{
 int unsorted[SIZE] = {6,2,5,-1,11,3,17,-9,1,10};
 quicksort(unsorted,0,SIZE-1);
 cout << "The sorted array" << endl;
 for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
 {
    cout << unsorted[i] <<" ";
 }
 
}
```

Comment: Do you get some (diagnostic) output if you add the line `std::cout << "quicksort from " << p << " to " << q << "\n";` to your `quicksort` function (perhaps inside the `if`, but before could also help)?

Comment: What error or output you are getting?

Answer (score -1):

The code you pasted enters infinite recursion in the `quicksort` function. Also, I would recommend using `std::vector` and pass that by reference instead of using C-style arrays. The `std::vector` is a more flexible container.

Here is the corrected code https://onlinegdb.com/q4LxWciVC:

```
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 10
using namespace std;
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
  int temp = *a;
  *a  = *b;
  *b = temp;
}
int partition(int* array,int p, int q)
{
   int i = p-1;
   int pivot = array[q]; // make pivot the last element of the array


   for (int j{p};j<q;++j)
   {
       if (array[j] < pivot)
       {
           i++;
           swap(&array[i], &array[j]);
       }
   }

   swap(&array[i+1], &array[q]);

   return i+1;
}
void quicksort(int* array,int p,int q)
{
    if(p >= q){
        return;
    }
    
     std::cout<<"\n---------Reached here---------\n";
     int r = partition(array,p,q);
     quicksort(array, p, r-1);
     quicksort(array, r+1, q);
    
}
int main()
{
 int unsorted[SIZE] = {6,2,5,-1,11,3,17,-9,1,10};
 quicksort(unsorted,0,SIZE-1);
 cout << "The sorted array" << endl;
 for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
 {
    cout << unsorted[i] <<" ";
 }
 
}
```

Output:

---------Reached here---------

---------Reached here---------

---------Reached here---------

---------Reached here---------

---------Reached here---------

---------Reached here---------

The sorted array
-9 -1 1 2 3 5 6 10 11 17

Comment: Your code doesn't use OP's `swap()` that can be removed.

Comment: @273K it was using the function from `std::` namespace. I don't get the downvote?

Comment: You've defined your own `swap` function, yet you are also making `std::swap` available. You don't need to define your own swap function (that definition should be deleted entirely), and you should generally avoid `using namespace std`.

Comment: @CodyGray I avoid `using namespace std`, it was in the OP's code. I modified and correct his code.

Comment: **I modified and correct his code.** A code only answer is not considered as good. You have not explained what  in OP's code is wrong.

Comment: While you have explained "enters infinite recursion", you have not explained why. You should explain in words what needed to be changed, before demonstrating the change with code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made the code work by replacing r with r+1. It worked. As for the C style arrays , I am new to C++ from C so I still have those habits.